# ¿Alguien sabe como resolver el problema "image "pyimage1" doesn't exist" en python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pillow

**Explicacion:**
Hoy me pasé a linux y con ello mis proyectos en python, en windows funcionaban bien, pero en linux no, el problema que tengo es que con pillow / PIL intento abrir una imagen usando tkinter, pero al abrirla me dice que dicha no existe, verifique las rutas con las que estaba trabajando y todo estaba en orden, la ruta de la imagen estaba bien, y al momento de borrar la imagen del programa y en vez de eso poner un boton normal, el programa funcionó correctamente.
A continuacion les dejo el codigo con el que tengo error:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb
import random
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

tkmb.showinfo("Explicación", "Bienvenido al juego de adivina el numero, tendras que adivinar un numero del 1 al 100, mediante vayas digitando numeros se te irán dando pistas, se te informará si tu numero es menor o mayor al numero por adivinar. Suerte")

root = Tk()

root.title("Adivina el numero")


intentos = 1

numero_maquina = random.randint(1,100)

marco = LabelFrame(root,
                   text="Digite un numero del 1 al 100",
                   padx=50,
                   pady=50)
marco.pack(padx=25, pady=10)

numero_usuario = Entry(marco,width=30)
numero_usuario.insert(0,"Escriba un numero...")
numero_usuario.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x : numero_usuario.delete(0, END))
numero_usuario.pack()

root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

root.resizable(False, False)

ruta_raiz = os.path.dirname(__file__)
ruta_boton = os.path.join(ruta_raiz, "boton")

boton = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.join(ruta_boton, "button.png")).resize((80,40)))

def verificar_numero():
    global intentos
    try:
        numero = int(numero_usuario.get())
        
        if numero < numero_maquina:
            tkmb.showinfo("Pista", f"El numero es mas alto. Digite un numero mayor que {numero}")
            intentos += 1
        elif numero > numero_maquina:
            tkmb.showinfo("Pista", f"El numero es mas bajo. Digite un numero menor que {numero}")
            intentos += 1
        else:
            tkmb.showinfo("Felicidades", f"Has adivinado el numero en {intentos} intentos")
            root.destroy()
    except:
        tkmb.showerror("¡Error!", "Valor no válido.")
        intentos += 1

boton_enviar = Button(root, image=boton , border=0 ,command=verificar_numero)
boton_enviar.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Al querer ejecutar el programa se ejecuta bien el messagebox.showinfo pero al querer abrir la ventana me saltó un error en la consola y es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/coloco0954/Documents/Cursos/Python/Día 18/proyecto/proyecto_grafica.py", line 56, in <module>
    boton_enviar = Button(root, image=boton , border=0 ,command=verificar_numero)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2650, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

como dice en el error dice que la imagen que intento llamar en el boton no existe, verifiqué la ruta del boton y todo está correcto, aclaro que este mismo programa lo probé en Windows y todo funcionó correctamente pero cuando me pasé a linux es cuando tuve el error.

Espero y puedan ayudarme porfavor.

Comment: Hola, no veo nada mal en el código, ante la duda lo he probado y funciona perfectamente (en Linux, Python 3.11.5, tk 8.6.13/tcl-8.6.13 y pillow 10.1.0). ¿Has provado a ejecutar el script directamente en la terminal y no a traves del IDE? Es decir, abrir una terminal y ejecutar `python "/home/coloco0954/Documents/Cursos/Python/Día 18/proyecto/proyecto_grafica.py"` Prueba y comenta el resultado,  si el error no se produce entonces el IDE o el debugger están interfiriendo, si se sigue produciendo agrega tu version de tkinter y tcl a ver si damos con la causa.

Comment: Probé tanto en la terminal como en el IDE y en ambos arrojó el mismo error, pero ahora que mencionas el tema de las versiones de python a lo mejor ese es el problema, la versión que tengo instalada en el sistema es la 3.8.10, consideraré actualizarla y te cuento el resultado

Comment: En un rato paso las versiones de tkinter y tcl

Comment: Te recomiendo que no actualices el interprete del sistema de forma aislada si no estas seguro de las implicaciones que tiene en tu distro concreta, o puede que termines así: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/609726/15089 o peor. Usa [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) y entornos virtuales (con [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) de la stdlib por ejemplo) para separar las dependencias entre tus proyectos y entre el propio SO. Existen también otras opciones mas avanzadas como contenedores (Docker), pero Pyenv + venv es una ocion muy simple.

Comment: Logŕe solucionarlo, tuve que actualizar python y Pillow

Answer (score 0):

Este problema tambien me ocurria a mi, la explicacion que me dieron es que tcl elimina todo registro de tu imagen al momento de ejecutar el comando y por lo tanto para las proximos comandos la imagen ya no existe en las variables por lo que tira error.

Para mantener referenciada la imagen la solucion consiste en vincular el widget en mas de una instancia a la imagen

```
boton_enviar = Button(root, image=boton , border=0 ,command=verificar_numero)
boton_enviar[ "image"] = boton
boton_enviar.pack()

Cuentame como te va
```

Comment: Ahh, gracias por la informacion y solución, al final opté por volver a windows, pero cuando llegue a pasarme nuevamente a linux nuevamente y me vuelva a salir el error lo intentaré